# jQuery post function not working! Don not know why

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi I am a little new to web programming and I ran into a problem with the $.post function.

right now I have some images in my index page and when I click on them I want to:

1) go to a second page called viewAlbum

2) get the source of the clicked image and store it in a `$_SESSION['album']` located in the viewAlbum.php page.

index.php:

```
<a href = \"viewAlbum.php\"><img src = " . $url . " alt = " . $caption . " title = " . $caption . "/></a>

(caption is a string)

script.js:

$('img').click(function(){
        if(window.location == index){
            console.log("1");
            var src = $(this).attr("src");
            var data = {"Album": src};
        }
}

viewAlbum.php:

<?php
if(isset($_POST['Album'])){ 
    print("worked>");
    $_SESSION['album'] = $_POST['Album'];
}
else{ 
print("did not work");
}

?>
```

This is printing "did not work" and I do not know how to fix it. Please help!

Comment: Well and where exactly is the $.post you mention in the title?

Comment: you have not used  $.post in your code

Comment: sorry I did not notice and I left it out in the process of copying..

the code is: 

$('img').click(function(){
        if(window.location == index){
            console.log("1");
            var src = $(this).attr("src");
            var data = {"Album": src};
            $.post("viewAlbum.php", {"album": src});
        }
}

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting any POST data in the index or JS.
Take a look at the [JQuery $.post(](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)) function to see how this is done.

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax

```
   $.ajax({
            url: "/name.php",
            type: "post",
            data: your data
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AJAX to send data to and .php Script via JavaScript!.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

first do not forget to fix your html and add the `name` tag in your element. in your case,

```
name="Album"
```

your should add ajax to your script.js :

```
  $.ajax({
            url: "/name.php",
            type: "post",
            data: your data
        });
```

also see the api document for [Jquery.Post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I just do not understand why I should change the html? Thanks!

Also Included the $.ajax call (I basically pasted it and changed the variables accordingly) but still did not work :(